# Google Script - Last modify date changed through a script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem and I couldn't find any solution to it.

What I need: 
To change the Last modified date of the spreadsheet if anything has been modified in the spreadsheet by a script.

What's wrong:
The last modified date changes only if I physically open the file and make a change. However, if the change has been done automatically by the script the last modified date is not changing.

Background:
I have a google spreadsheet which is linked to an external mobile app as a data source. The problem is that the external app synchronizes the data only if the last modified date has changed. I can't change this as it's an external ready to use app. Now, my google spreadsheet is updated from another spreadsheet by a script every 5 minutes but even if a new data is added to the file, the file's last modified date doesn't change (if I add this data manually obviously it would change).

I have tested various options adding a temporary tab and deleting it, renaming the file, etc. but nothing seems to be changing the date although all these things will change the date if done manually.

I was also looking for something similar to 'touch' command in linux which would change the date but i couldn't find it out how to implement something similar in google scripts.

thanks,

Comment: Every time a Spreadsheet is modified via Google App Script, the change/date is registered for user whose authority the script is running. You can see the history of changes made in **File > See revision history**. How are you getting the "Last modified date of the spreadsheet"?

Comment: I am just checking the last modified date displayed in the google drive against this file and this is what the external app is checking. Can i force it to show the latest date from the revision history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive API has a [touch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/touch) method, but you need to use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) (That must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). In the Script Editor select **Resources > Advanced Google services**... and then enable it in the **Google Developers Console**.)

Once enabled you can use it like this:

```
function touch() {
  var fileid = 'YOUR_FILE_ID';
  Drive.Files.touch(fileid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.